# Transclusion within nested element with jQuery Steps

Tags: angularjs, jquery-plugins, angularjs-directive, jquery-steps

I'm attempting to integrate jQuery Steps (Wizard generator) in an Angular.js application with a nested Google Maps element from angular-google-maps (https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps).

However, I get this error:
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngTransclude/orphan - "Illegal use of ngTransclude directive in the template! No parent directive that requires a transclusion found."

It looks like I have been using $compile during the Angular.js link phase, but the `<div ng-transclude></div>` is not being replaced in the nested element.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app='tr'>
  <div outer=1>
      XZY987
      <inner>ABC123</inner>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var ngApp = angular.module('tr', []);

ngApp.directive('outer', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, ele) {
            ele.wrapInner('<div class="steps-wrapper">');
            var steps = ele.children('.steps-wrapper').steps();
            $compile(steps)(scope);
        }
    };
}]);
ngApp.directive('inner', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        template: 'WWW <div ng-transclude></div> UUU'
    };
```

});

Plnkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/GYE57Dz4W4sLHlvSt6VQ?p=preview

Here, the 'outer' element represents the jQuery Steps 'wrapped' custom directive and the 'inner' element is the Google Maps custom directive with a transclude and a template.

I've been scratching my head on this one most of today so I hope its an easy solution for someone else to point out for me!

Thanks in advance...
Nigel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `inner`is getting compiled twice. You might solve the problem using the `compile` function instead of the `link` one:

```
    compile: function(ele){
        ele.wrapInner('<div class="steps-wrapper"></div>');
        var steps = ele.children('.steps-wrapper').steps();
    }
```

You could also comment the `$compile(steps)(scope);` link in the link function as far as you don't have any other code to be compiled inside the `outer` tag.

**Updated plunkr**: http://plnkr.co/edit/SKqpgT38vGBA92YyRe66?p=preview

Comment: Thanks @knut... it now makes more sense to me, as jQuery Steps does a DOM transform, so its better to do this in the compile( ) phase, prior to scope being attached. Also, link( ) is actually a 'post-link' function by default.